# I am trying to integrate stripe in my website, but I got some problem

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

When I use test key then form showing stripe input file:

```html
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <label for="card-element">

  </label>
  <div id="card-element">
      <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>

  <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
</div>
```

And when I set the live key, then the form is not showing the input field. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: where and how are you setting the live key? Please add that information to the question

Comment: please check below i answered here

Comment: is it problem for http ?

Comment: solved http problem